# Oracle ADF Add secondaryPattern to Date in Query Component

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I am working on secondary pattern on date object in Query component in ADF. I know that the default date format is "dd/MM/yyyy", I would like to add another pattern for "yyyy-MM-dd". Please let me know how can I implement this logic.

Answer (score 2):

To change the format type of a Timestamp attribute in your **View Object** do as follow :

- Open your **View Object**
- Go to the "**attribute**" tab
- select your Timestamp attribute that need to have another date format pattern
- go to the "**UI Hint**" sub tab
- Change *Format Type* to "**Simple Date**"
- Change *Format* to **your expected pattern** (in your case yyyy-MM-dd)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would like to keep both of the pattern (i.e. dd/MM/yyyy and yyyy-MM-dd). For example, when I type in '2019-03-14', the date field will still possible to recognize as a valid date format.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible but you could try removing the                                <af:convertDateTime pattern=""/> in your jsf so it will not validate the format in jsf. Seems weird to me that you would have an inputDate with two formats.